# Alternative for Buffalo wing sauce

Tags: sauce

What can I use if my family does not like Buffalo wing sauce or any hot sauce for that matter?
I found a recipe for wings and potato casserole that sounds good but not if it's hot.

Comment: Does your family not like the flavors associated with hot sauce? Or do they just not like the "burn" of the hot sauce?

Comment: What is the result you are trying to get?

Comment: There are plenty of places that serve wings with more mild sauces ... barbecue sauce, sweet & sour, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Really, any sauce you use with other savory meet dishes can be nice on chicken wings. Options include:

- BBQ sauce
- most Asian ready made sauces at your grocery store (teriyaki, sweet and sour, etc., even better make a homemade version of one of these sauces)
- honey mustard
- melted butter (or extra virgin olive oil) with garlic, Parmesan cheese, and your favorite herbs
- lemon or lime juice & salt (possibly add honey if you like it sweet)
- vinegar & salt
- real maple syrup and salt
- [peanut butter and jelly sauce](http://www.food.com/recipe/wings-peanut-butter-and-jelly-wings-512536) (some of these recipes include chilies, which you can ignore)
- you can even wrap wings in bacon, for a dryer but quite flavorful wing